# Image is downloaded as .png after cropping the image

Tags: reactjs, svg, canvas

I have modified code from repo to crop the images.
Objective is to upload the file. In accepted format.Crop the file and then download or upload the same to the cloudinary.

While I upload the svg and crop the file the downloaded file is ".png". Kindly help me in debugging the same.

```
handleDownloadClick = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        const { imgSrc } = this.state;

        //To handle the name of the file while downloading

        var fileName = `${this.fileInputRef.current.files[0].name}`;
        var remove_after = fileName.indexOf(".");
        var finalFileName = fileName.substring(0, remove_after);

        if (imgSrc) {
            const canvasRef = this.imagePreviewCanvasRef.current;

            const { imgSrcExt } = this.state;
            console.log(imgSrcExt);
            const imageData64 = canvasRef.toDataURL("image/" + imgSrcExt);

            const myFilename = `${finalFileName}`;

            // file to be uploaded
            const myNewCroppedFile = base64StringtoFile(
                imageData64,
                myFilename
            );
            console.log(myNewCroppedFile);
            // download file
            downloadBase64File(imageData64, myFilename);
            this.handleClearToDefault();
        }
    };
```

Comment: `image/svg` is not a type canvas can export - because an SVG isn't actually an image, but a canvas is (SVG doesn't hold any pixel data directly unless embedded as something else). If you tried `image/svg` as output, canvas will ignore it and just use `image/png` as the default since that value is not valid.

Comment: Hi thanks for the information. Is there any approach to download the image as svg

Comment: Load the SVG nodes from the file, modify the nodes themselves to crop, and then upload the changed SVG nodes as text. `SVG data !== pixels` at all, so going through canvas will destroy your svg data. You would need to modify the `viewBox` property on the SVG root to 'crop' an svg, but I foresee a lot of exceptions that will make it complicated. Why do you need to crop an SVG anyway? Usually its just not an accepted file format for cropping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To crop a SVG you need to change the `viewBox` attribute and the SVG `width` and `height` attributes.

Example crops and pads SVG logo

```js
var size = 300;
   const baseSize = 300, resizeBy = 20, minSize = 30;
crop.addEventListener("click", () => resizeSvg(-resizeBy));
pad.addEventListener("click", () => resizeSvg(resizeBy));

function resizeSvg(amount) {
    size = size + amount < minSize ? minSize : size + amount;
    const edge = (baseSize - size) / 2
    svgLogo.setAttribute("width", size);
    svgLogo.setAttribute("height", size);
    svgLogo.setAttribute("viewBox", [edge, edge, size, size].join(" "));

}
```

```css
svg {border: 2px solid}
```

```html
<button id="crop">Crop 20px</button>
<button id="pad">Pad 20px</button><br>

<svg id="svgLogo" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="300" height="300" viewBox="0 0 300 300">

  <title>SVG Logo</title> <defs> <g id="SVG" fill="#ffffff" transform="scale(2) translate(20,79)"> <path id="S" d="M 5.482,31.319 C2.163,28.001 0.109,23.419 0.109,18.358 C0.109,8.232 8.322,0.024 18.443,0.024 C28.569,0.024 36.782,8.232 36.782,18.358 L26.042,18.358 C26.042,14.164 22.638,10.765 18.443,10.765 C14.249,10.765 10.850,14.164 10.850,18.358 C10.850,20.453 11.701,22.351 13.070,23.721 L13.075,23.721 C14.450,25.101 15.595,25.500 18.443,25.952 L18.443,25.952 C23.509,26.479 28.091,28.006 31.409,31.324 L31.409,31.324 C34.728,34.643 36.782,39.225 36.782,44.286 C36.782,54.412 28.569,62.625 18.443,62.625 C8.322,62.625 0.109,54.412 0.109,44.286 L10.850,44.286 C10.850,48.480 14.249,51.884 18.443,51.884 C22.638,51.884 26.042,48.480 26.042,44.286 C26.042,42.191 25.191,40.298 23.821,38.923 L23.816,38.923 C22.441,37.548 20.468,37.074 18.443,36.697 L18.443,36.692 C13.533,35.939 8.800,34.638 5.482,31.319 L5.482,31.319 L5.482,31.319 Z"/><path id="V" d="M 73.452,0.024 L60.482,62.625 L49.742,62.625 L36.782,0.024 L47.522,0.024 L55.122,36.687 L62.712,0.024 L73.452,0.024 Z"/> <path id="G" d="M 91.792,25.952 L110.126,25.952 L110.126,44.286 L110.131,44.286 C110.131,54.413 101.918,62.626 91.792,62.626 C81.665,62.626 73.458,54.413 73.458,44.286 L73.458,44.286 L73.458,18.359 L73.453,18.359 C73.453,8.233 81.665,0.025 91.792,0.025 C101.913,0.025 110.126,8.233 110.126,18.359 L99.385,18.359 C99.385,14.169 95.981,10.765 91.792,10.765 C87.597,10.765 84.198,14.169 84.198,18.359 L84.198,44.286 L84.198,44.286 C84.198,48.481 87.597,51.880 91.792,51.880 C95.981,51.880 99.380,48.481 99.385,44.291 L99.385,44.286 L99.385,36.698 L91.792,36.698 L91.792,25.952 L91.792,25.952 Z"/> </g> </defs>
 <path id="base" fill="#000" d="M8.5,150 H291.5 V250 C291.5,273.5 273.5,291.5 250,291.5 H50 C26.5,291.5 8.5,273.5 8.5,250 Z"/>
   <g stroke-width="38.0086" stroke="#000">
     <g id="svgstar" transform="translate(150, 150)">
       <path id="svgbar" fill="#ffb13b" 
         d="M-84.1487,-15.8513 a22.4171,22.4171 0 1 0 0,31.7026 h168.2974 a22.4171,22.4171 0 1 0 0,-31.7026 Z"/>
       <use xlink:href="#svgbar" transform="rotate(45)"/><use xlink:href="#svgbar" transform="rotate(90)"/><use xlink:href="#svgbar" transform="rotate(135)"/> </g></g> <use xlink:href="#svgstar"/><use xlink:href="#base" opacity="0.85"/><use xlink:href="#SVG"/>

</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

Canvas is used to manipulate pixel based data, so it can take an SVG in and render it as an image on the canvas, but you can't actually get the SVG out as SVG's aren't *pixels*, they are descriptions of objects. So in order to store the image as an SVG again, you would have to embed the pixel data into an SVG element - but at this point, it makes no difference. Cropping an SVG can't be done using canvas, as canvas renders the pixels and loses the SVG data.

This also explains why asking a canvas for a `image/svg` output doesn't work - it will just fall back on output a canvas *can describe*, pixel based formats like `jpeg` or `png`. And so you get a `.png` file.

Cropping an SVG is a matter of changing attributes on the `svg` tags, like `viewBox`, `width` and `height`, and they would require a wildly different process than using canvas.

### Example SVG Crop

In order to crop SVG images, you don't need to adjust their width and height properties, just the `viewBox` (width and height don't matter that much here). Here's an example:

```js
const svg = document.getElementById( 'svg' );

document.getElementById( 'crop' ).addEventListener( 'input', event => {
  
  const size = event.target.value;
  const coordinate = ((1 - size) / 2);
  
  svg.setAttribute( 'viewBox', `${coordinate} ${coordinate} ${size} ${size}` );
   
})
```

```html
<svg id="svg" width="100px" height="100px" viewBox="0 0 1 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <circle cx=".5" cy=".5" r=".5" fill="red" />
  <circle cx=".5" cy=".5" r=".4" fill="blue" />
  <circle cx=".5" cy=".5" r=".3" fill="green" />
  <circle cx=".5" cy=".5" r=".2" fill="yellow" />
  <circle cx=".5" cy=".5" r=".1" fill="pink" />
</svg>

<br />
<p>Change cropping on SVG using viewBox</p>
<input type="range" id="crop" min=".1" max="1" step=".01" />
```

Comment: Sure. My approach would have been the same.It is just that i need to run it through the cropper once for other file formats as well.

Comment: Then detect and use a different cropping function for SVG - because you are losing SVG data in the process. What was the point then anyway? Its usually better to save the SVG as it takes less space in most circumstances than images. Anyhow, I added a way to 'crop' SVG files.